# Rails devise before_destroy user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, callback

I wan't to notify the admin when a user deletes his account. My idea is to use the before_destroy validation to send an email from within the model.

This is probably better done in the controller but I don't want to subclass the devise controller because I think I could break something.

The problem is that the model can't access the current_user, which was my first thought about how to "get" the corresponding user account. But the model has to somehow know which user account is meant to be destroyed, right?, so there has to be some kind of variable being passed.

I've looked into the devise controller at github and it seems like everything is done using "resources".

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

I can't figure out the last part, how could I access the id / or user object?

Comment: use an Observer.  On the event of destroy, send email.

Comment: I don't understand. If the user is deleting their own account, then you already *know* the current user--it's the user model object that's being deleted.

Comment: This means it is "self" beeing destroyed? So I could say "self.id" to get the id of the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add a hook in your model and send the mail..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_destroy :notify_admin


  private

  def notify_admin
    YourMailer.user_destroyed(self).deliver
  end

end
```

The "self" will be your current_user object..

Comment: Thank you very much! I was at this point but failed with the following, isn't this possible? (Inside the notify_admin method: @user = User.find(self).includes([:courses, :enrolments]).scoped

Comment: You already have the instance..you must not find it again :-). I do not know your db schema but I think you have to change your query. I would recommend to work on the instance level and not on the class level, because you already have the instance..

Comment: Courses and enrolments are two has_many / through relations of users. Hmm ok, I understand what you mean about the instance, but I need to include these relations to minimize later sql queries. Isn't that done through the model?

Comment: Can't you simple call self.enrollments and self.courses..? I think that's ok. With the correct indexes it should not be a real performance killer..

Answer (score 1):

Something like that could work:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def destroy
    # You have access to current_user here

    super
  end
end
```

Comment: How/where would I name and place the file? And do the other methods of super work properly then? Or do I have to define everyone and call super in it?

Comment: `app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`.

Comment: Also make sure to have some mapping like this in your `routes.rb`:

  `devise_for :users, 
    :controllers => {
      :registrations => 'users/registrations'
    }`